# Знаки препинания в предложении со словом "значит"?

Tags: пунктуация

**После удаления средства на коже не появились покраснения, шелушение и отек – значит его смело можно использовать для лечения ротовой полости.**

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать сложноподчиненное предложение:

Если после удаления средства на коже не появились покраснения, шелушение и отек,   значит, его смело можно использовать для лечения ротовой полости.

ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ ― двойной союз (союзное образование), включает вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ.

Comment: А если нельзя использовать слово "если"?

Comment: Ваш вариант (с вопросительным знаком) тоже подходит, но он должен соответствовать общему свободному  стилю речи, где возможно обращение к читателю.  Вариант с СПП - нейтральный, более строгий.  А вот бессоюзный вариант с тире  не совсем подходящий, так как предложение распространенное и в нем сложно выразить условные отношения с помощью одной интонации. Сравнить (нераспространенное предложение):" Прислал он мне крест - значит, он меня любит".

Answer (score 0):

Можно ли так?

**После удаления средства на коже не появились покраснения, шелушение и отек? Значит его смело можно использовать для лечения ротовой полости.**

Comment: Можно, только после "значит" запятая, это же вводное